# cant switch tabs to active with routerLinkActive in mat-tab-navbar

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using mat-tab-navbar for app navigation with lazy loaded modules. I tried using RouterLinkActive but cant switch tab state to active when clicked. Please look at the screenshot bellow.

navbar.component.html

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar fxHide.xs>
    <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let link of navLinks" routerLink="{{ link.location }}" routerLinkActive
        #rla="routerLinkActive" [active]="rla.isActive">
        <span>{{ link.label | uppercase }}</span>
    </a>
</nav>
```

[Result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dxPR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response. I've figured it out and it works!

navbar.component.html

```
    <nav mat-tab-nav-bar mat-align-tabs="center">
    <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let link of navLinks" routerLink="{{ link.location }}"
        (click)="activelink=link.location" [active]="activelink==link.location">
        <span>{{ link.label | uppercase }}</span>
    </a>
</nav>
```

navbar.component.ts

```
  activelink = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar fxHide.xs>
    <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let link of navLinks" routerLink="{{ link.location }}" [active]="routerLinkActive">
        <span>{{ link.label | uppercase }}</span>
    </a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could instead import the component into the mat-tab like this:

```
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <label>Example</label>
    </ng-template>
    <app-example></app-example>
  </mat-tab>
```